# Conflict between amsmath, FrenchPro and cleveref

Tags: amsmath, cleveref, french

I'm hitting a conflict between `amsmath`, `e-french` and `cleveref` that causes equation references to be undefined. Here's a minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[french]{mlp}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{bla}
e = mc^2.
\end{equation}

Consid\'erons~\ref{bla}.

\end{document}
```

If I leave out either `amsmath`, `mlp` or `cleveref`, everything looks fine. I don't think the issue is with `mlp` itself; I get the same error when I load a local installation of `e-french` directly with `\usepackage{french}`.

I know `cleveref` should be loaded last. I tried several permutations, but with no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!!

ps: the MWE example above doesn't benefit from `cleveref`, but my actual document does.

Comment: As far as I know, the `e-french` package was recently updated, but only in a superficial way and has been basically unmaintained for more than a decade.

Comment: What can the `mlp` package do that `babel` package can't do as well?

Comment: @Mico Maybe nothing, I'm not sure. I've been using FrenchPro for years.

Comment: I can't discern differences by reading the documentation of e-french or babel-french. The latter seems to have come a long way. I'm using it at the moment as it's not in conflict with amsmath, etc. Thanks! I'll leave the question open just in case.

Comment: I would say e-french and cleveref are incompatible. You will have to choose.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer As I mentioned, you can use them together. Just not together with amsmath.